# Reading all text files in a network path in a WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, text

How can i read all the text files in a network path in C# Winforms?. The text files name are always changing.

example:

- **ABC-GD09538.txt**
- **ADB-JK3949.txt**
- **GJD-KGL9495-txt**

The format of each text file when opened is:

```
Some Text
Some Text
Some Text
Some Text

[data start]
"Data1"|"Data2"|"Data3"|"Data4"|"Data5"|"Data5"|"Data6"
[data end]
```

I would also like to ignore the "some text" part of text file and proceed the text file reading on the line [data start] and end it on the line [data end] then finally perform a query to database and then insert the data received from text files to a table.

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: at the moment none, i just need an idea so i can work on it. Im not familiarize with this kind of scenario.

Comment: See e.g. `Directory.GetFiles()` and `StreamReader`. More than that and your question is too broad. Try something. _Anything_. Show [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), explain what the code does and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the MSDN website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370%28v=vs.110%29.aspx**

This will enumerate through the c:\ directory and provide you a list of each .txt file (I took out the Where clause).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                        select new
                        {
                            File = file,
                            Line = line
                        };

            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} files found.", files.Count().ToString());
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

To go through each file and read the "DATA" information. Make sure to pass the parameter for 'f' if you make this a separate function.

```
        try
        {
            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.file))
                {
                    string readLine;
                    do
                    {
                        readLine = sr.ReadLine();
                        string[] readLineSplit = readLine.Split('|');
                        if (readLineSplit.Length > 1)
                        {
                            //Make call to database for query and update it with the readSplit.
                        }

                    } while (!sr.EndOfStream);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I would suggest creating a new thread on how to make a query and update a database. You make no mention on what database it is, table structure or otherwise.

Be safe,

-Rob

Comment: im using mysql database

Comment: Im getting error: The name 'readSplit' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @KevinRodriguez - I think you'll find that `readSplit` is a typo. Look more closely at the code and you'll be able to figure out what it should be.

Comment: yes thank you, it is working now, i just need to figure out how it will insert/update the records into the database.

Comment: On a 0 byte file, `readLine = sr.ReadLine();` returns null. Your code will throw an exception. The common syntax is `while ((readLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null) ...`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the easiest way I know to get all of the data items out:

```
string[] data = 
    Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(@"Path\To\Folder", "*.txt")
        .SelectMany(f =>
            File
                .ReadAllLines(f)
                .SkipWhile(l => l != "[data start]")
                .Skip(1)
                .TakeWhile(l => l != "[data end]")
                .SelectMany(l => l.Split('|')))
        .ToArray();
```

I get this kind of result:

[image: result]

Then you can just save the array of strings to the db.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following will read all `.txt` files in a specified network directory and skip all lines until it reaches `[data start]` in the text file.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

string networkPath = "\\\\Network\\Path";
foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(networkPath, "*.txt"))
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(path).SkipWhile(x => !x.Contains("[data start]")))
    {
         //Do something with line here
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i display the all the text data on a gridview?

Comment: @KevinRodriguez - Please ask a new question if you need to display this in a grid view. You shouldn't tack on new questions to your current one - you'll end up annoying everyone.